# Grails Shiro plugin create read only tables

Tags: mysql, grails, shiro

Why grails shiro plugin create read only tables in mysql for roles and permissions? i create controllers and actions and add them into permissions for registered role in BootStrap file. but every time when i want to add new action into permissions, I must delete the tables and recreate them via rerun the app. how I can edit permissions table manually or maybe I must not create roles and permissions in BootStrap for prod.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure these tables are readonly? You couldn't even write to them in the bootstrap...
Try to modify them with `.save(failOnError:true)` and see if you get an error message.
If you don't get an error, post your code with which you try to modify the roles and permissions and I'll help you to sort this out...

Comment: in code I can read/write in that tables, but when via GUI (Navicat/Workbench) I can't edit that tables

Comment: Ah! I guess I now know your problem... Some DB GUIs have a problem with editing tables without  a primary key. But you cann still add and removerows.